# Where can I find an average transaction value chart?

Tags: transactions, charts

I'm curious on what is the average amount of BTC transacted per transaction. I'd basically like to combine [blockchain.info's Estimated Transaction Value](https://blockchain.info/charts/estimated-transaction-volume) and [Number of Transactions Per Day](https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions) charts.

I'm writing my own script locally, but I wonder if this kind of info is already available online somewhere ([googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+average+transaction+value) for "bitcoin average transaction value" didn't help).

Answer (score 9):

This chart can answer that question for any period you choose:

https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/historical/1w-f-txval_per_avg-11101

Measured in BTC, the average transaction value was naturally the highest in the early days of bitcoin when its value was much less in fiat terms

Comment: This seems to be slightly different from what I'm looking for. Tradeblock's transaction value seems to be the total output (excludes only the transaction fee), while BlockChain.info's estimated transaction value also tries to exclude change output(s).